# Changing the contact dashboard display

Tags: dashboard

I need to change the contact dashboard that I display to users so it does not show a [Renew Now] link in the Membership section.

Thanks
Miguel Peirano

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity: why would you want to do that?
You can remove it in the css, by adding a little jQuery to a template and then add the template to the Contact Summary, or by changing your specific copy of the Summary template. You can get more information on how to do this on 
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customize+Built-in+Screens

Answer (score 2):

I'm fully sure I understood your need, why wouldn't you want your members to renew?

If you are using your membership in a "non standard" way, it might be easier to just remove anything about membership from their dashboard (it's something that you can configure via a UI).

But assuming it's just about the renew link, the clean way is to let civi add that renew link (ie. do not modify the core) and create an extension that will alter and hide or remove it

To build an extension, use civix, or take an existing one as example, then use the [dashboard hook](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_dashboard) and alter the membership section, or as erik suggested, just add a  block to display:none that link

Comment: Thanks! We are an international academic association. We don't want our members to interact with the renewal process this way because we have a very complex membership structure with pricing depending on country of residence, relationship to the institution, number of representatives of each institutional user, etc. etc. We prefer sending each category of member the correct CP via checksum near the end of the year. We decided to provide status/relationships information with a Drupal view and do away with the dashboard. Thanks for your help, it has been very educational for future needs.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Renew Now Link from the contact Dashboard go to Administer| CiviMember| CiviMember Component Settings.
In the Default online membership renewal page deselect the default Contribution page that is selected. Or better still just put the drop down on -select- and click Save.

Comment: Will that stop a Renew Now link showing for someone who did join via online? I think not. The help says "If you select a default online contribution page for self-service membership renewals, a "renew" link pointing to that page will be displayed on the Contact Dashboard for memberships which were entered offline. You will need to ensure that the membership block for the selected online contribution page includes any currently available memberships." ie it is specific for 'offline' entries, so those contacts have 'somewhere' to go to renew. Is Miguel aiming to remove it for all Members?

Comment: Ran out of room ;-) Your answer is really helpful as it points to a feature that many users, myself included, don't know about or easily forget about.